# Подключение файлов в phpStorm

Tags: php, phpstorm

Всем привет.
Структура сайта:

```
source/
  config/nav.php, init.php
  layout/header.php
  index.php
```

В *header.php* пытаюсь подключить *nav.php* через `require_once`:

```
<?php require_once './config/navigation.php'; ?>
```

Но phpStorm ругается, что нет такого пути. Если писать через ../config - то ошибка php

> Warning: require_once(../config/navigation.php): failed to open
>   stream: No such file or directory in
>   C:\OSPanel\domains\source\layout\header.php on line 1

Как правильно прописать относительный путь?
Заранее спасибо за ответ.

Comment: В структуре вы пишите `config/nav.php`, а в коде подключаете `config/navigation.php`?

Comment: структуру условно написал. И там и там я пишу navigation

Comment: тогда используйте полные пути